# Google Analytics's custom metrics and different aggregation functions

Tags: google-analytics

Consider defining `hit` level custom dimensions and custom metrics in Goggle Analytics, event though it is not mentioned in Google's documents but I think if some hits are logged in GA, their custom-metric values are summed within each group of custom-dimension.

Now my question is, is there a way I can show other statistic measures of the gathered custom-metric value? Like average, min, max, and standard deviation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately this is not currently possible. It's something a lot of people want though.

At this time in order to get things like what you've asked for (as well as other things like mean, median, average, etc.), you'll have to calculate it yourself.

One relatively easy way to do this is to run the report using the [Google Analytics Spreadsheet Add-on](https://developers.google.com/analytics/solutions/google-analytics-spreadsheet-add-on) and then use Google Sheet's functions to calculate that stuff automatically.

Comment: Thanks for introducing the add-on, but I don't see how can I use it to include functions like average, min, max or standard deviation!? Such aggregation functions need raw data to work with but the demos I've seen of Spreadsheet Add-on the metrics are imported to a spreadsheet aggregated! Could you please tell me how to calculate average for a metric which GA only calculates sum for?

Comment: You'd have to subdivide the metric by some dimension and then calculate the computed value. As an example, you could run a query that returns pageviews by date over the last 30 days. That would give you 30 metric results that you could calculate the median from.

Answer (score 0):

If you configure the data instead as a custom dimension instead of a custom metric, you can then export each value and use the corresponding number of pageviews/events/whatever as the frequency of that value, and then later calculate the kind of statistics that you require.

E.g.

row: 1,
dimension1: Banana,
dimension2: 1,
pageviews: 500

row: 2,
dimension1: Banana,
dimension2: 2,
pageviews: 100

Mean(Banana) = (1*500 + 2*100)/(500+100) = 1.167

Answer (score 0):

You can calculate an average by creating calculated metrics in the view settings - then you can divide a custom metric by the number of users/sessions/pageviews to calculate an average.

Use the calculated metric in a custom report and you'll have an average for each row in the report.